# Magento 2: How do I load a cart populated by the REST API into the frontend?

Tags: magento2, module, plugin

Using the Magento REST API I am able to create and populate a cart on my external site, but I want customers to checkout on the actual Magento site. Right now I'm looking at creating a plugin for `Checkout\Controller\Cart\Index`. I want it to grab the `cart_id` from the request parameters and load that cart up to the session. Trouble is, I'm not really sure exactly where to start, and the documentation is lacking.

So far I have the plugin class written as:

```
class IndexPlugin
{
    public function beforeExecute() {
        $params = $this->getRequest()->getParams();
        if (isset($params['masked_id'])) {
            $quoteIdMask = $this->checkoutSession->quoteIdMaskFactory->create()->load($params['masked_id'], 'masked_id');
            $this->checkoutSession->setQuoteId($quoteIdMask->getQuoteId());
        }
    }
}
```

With the `di.xml` looking like:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Checkout\Controller\Cart\Index">
        <plugin name="restore-cart-by-mask"
            type="{Vendor}\{Module}\Plugin\Checkout\Controller\Cart\Index" sortOrder="10"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

I know this is a less than secure approach, so any guidance would be extremely appreciated.

Comment: Did you end up using that approach, or find a better solution?